# Process for processing data visualization

Tags: node.js, algorithm, plotly, sequence

I am currently developing a website that provides visualized data based on user-entered search queries. However, I've encountered issues during the data processing phase after visualizing the data using Plotly. I'm contemplating the appropriate server architecture for this project. The envisioned approach involves the client entering a search query, and the server then sending this query to the database, retrieving the relevant data, and subsequently using Plotly to generate visualizations. I intend to have the visualization process carried out on the server side, with the results then being provided to the client. Nevertheless, due to concerns about speed and implementation complexity, I am considering whether there might be alternative approaches worth considering.

Is there any other good alternative?

[image]

[image]

I thought of the same method as the above two images If you want to do this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you have any other good ideas and simple examples to implement

I worked on the front end with html, css, and js
The server uses nodejs and the database is built using mongodb